# How to have different behavior on element when it gets wrapped to another line

Tags: html, css

I have two inline-block elements on my header bar. The right side element is floated right, but when screen gets so narrow that it gets wrapped to another line, I'd like to center it instead.

EDIT: The first element content is user-submitted, so I don't know its width in advance.

Below I've included javascript-based solution of the behavior I'm looking for.

Is this possible to achieve by using only CSS?

```js
$(window).bind("resize", function() {
  var totalWidth = $('.container').width(),
    firstWidth = $('.first').width(),
    secondWidth = $('.second').width();
  if (totalWidth > firstWidth + secondWidth) {
    $(".container").addClass('one-line');
    $(".container").removeClass('two-lines');
  } else {
    $(".container").addClass('two-lines');
    $(".container").removeClass('one-line');
  }
});
```

```css
.container div {
  display: inline-block;
}
.container.one-line .second-container {
  float: right;
}
.container.two-lines .second-container {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container one-line">
  <div class="first">One and two lines layout: align left</div>
  <div class="second-container">
    <div class="second">One lne layout: align right. Two line layout: align center.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

/

Comment: CSS media queries is the right way to achieve this

Comment: @DeepakDavid Good suggestion, but the first element content is user-submitted - so I don't know in advance when the second element will wrap.

Comment: i don't know other solution with CSS apart from media queries.

Comment: You can always specify min-width and tackle that issue